# Can't seem to get Node.js Command Line to interpret what I write, keeps returning "..."?

Tags: windows, node.js

[image]

So honestly, I don't really 'get' what's going on here, I mean, can I open the regular windows cmd.exe and use node from there? Or does it have to be from the node.js command window? Can I move files around on my system using the node.js command window? And yes, I currently can't figure out how to get it to interpret what i write, although it was working perfect before, but now I cant seem to escape from '...' every line, with no response.

Thanks

Comment: The node.js command line or first running `cmd.exe` then `node` will give you the node command line interpreter. It will only under stand JavaScript code. So you can't move files, or give any command that runs on cmd.exe.

Answer (score 3):

I use Node on *nix, so I'm not sure if it's different in Windows.  But on *nix systems, the ellipses means it's waiting on you to finish a code block or the like.  You should be able to hit CTRL+C (again, might be different in Windows) to cancel out of the edit you're in or CTRL+Z to kill the REPL entirely.

Comment: Yes put in your answer that CTRL+C works on windows 7! Why tho, why copy? Also you can recreate the multi-line effect by entering a comma or beginning a function definition, and probably other ways.

Comment: RIght, the multi-line effect is waiting for you to close the statement you started. e.g. with a closing curly brace or the like.  CTRL+C is to Cancel the current input stream. It's a *nix thing, and the REPL was written for Linux first, so you're on that baggage.